# Change Text Color From NSAttributedString When UITableViewCell is Selected/Highlighted

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsattributedstring

I want to be able to change the text in my UITableView cells when they are tapped on (selected/highlighted). The content from each cell is derived from an NSAttributedString. Here is that code:

```
-(NSAttributedString*)formattedSubject:(int)state {
    if(formattedSubject!=nil) return formattedSubject;
    NSDictionary *boldStyle = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    if(state==1) {
        boldStyle = @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:16.0],NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.067 green:0.129 blue:0.216 alpha:1.0]};
    }
    else {
        boldStyle = @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:16.0],NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]};
    }
    NSDictionary* normalStyle = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0]};
    NSMutableAttributedString* articleAbstract = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:subject];
    [articleAbstract setAttributes:boldStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, subject.length)];
    [articleAbstract appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\n"]];
    int startIndex = [articleAbstract length];
    NSTimeInterval _interval=[datestamp doubleValue];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:_interval];
    NSDateFormatter *_formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [_formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy"];
    NSString* description = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"By %@ on %@",author,[_formatter stringFromDate:date]];
    [articleAbstract appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: description]];
    [articleAbstract setAttributes:normalStyle range:NSMakeRange(startIndex, articleAbstract.length - startIndex)];
    formattedSubject = articleAbstract;
    return formattedSubject;
}
```

As you can see, I would like the `boldStyle` text to be a certain color (given by `[UIColor colorWithRed:0.067 green:0.129 blue:0.216 alpha:1.0]`) when the state is "1", and white otherwise. I've currently tried the following modifications in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, as well as `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

**cellForRowAtIndexPath:**

```
NSIndexPath *path = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
if(path) {
    cell.textLabel.attributedText = [news formattedSubject:1];
}
else {
    cell.textLabel.attributedText = [news formattedSubject:0];
}
```

What I am doing here is checking if a cell is selected, and if so then I changed that cell's "attributedText" to the "0" format. However, this didn't work, and I suspected it was because the modification had to be made when the cell was actually selected. So I tried the following in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

**didSelectRowAtIndexPath:**

```
News *news = newsArray[indexPath.row];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.attributedText = [news formattedSubject:0];
```

However, it seems like the change is never made. I put an `NSLog` in the "else" part of the `boldStyle` if/else statement, and it was never written to the console.

Neither of my attempts at a solution have worked, and I've run out of ideas. How can I get the `NSAttributedString` to change when a cell is highlighted?

**Update:** It's also interesting that `normalStyle` text, which is by default black, **does** turn white when the cell is highlighted/selected when I add `cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but `boldStyle` text does not.

Answer (score 1):

I have problem the same, and..

`cell.textLabel.enable = NO;`

It just resolved

Answer (score 0):

In your **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method you are checking if a selectedIndexPath in this tableView exists.

```
NSIndexPath *path = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
if(path) {
```

I think you want to compare your indexPath and your selectedIndexPath. You should use isEqual: for that.

```
NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
if([selectedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]) {
```

Comment: I tried `News *news = newsArray[indexPath.row];` with `[path isEqual:news]` in the if statement, this made the `boldStyle` text white by default.

Comment: Your **cellForRowAtIndexPath** has a NSIndexPath parameter called indexPath. In this method you want to check if the current **cellForRowAtIndexPath:** is selected. You get the NSIndexPath of the tableView's **indexPathForSelectedRow**. Then you compare the two NSIndexPaths (with isEqual:).
`[path isEqual:news]` does not work because you are comparing a _NSIndexPath_ with _News_

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting the same result. The text is just white by default.